# Is $\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\,dx$ improper integral when $g(a)=0$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Is $\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\,dx$ improper integral when $g(a)=0$ ?
Or is it same with $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ ?

I think it is improper integral, so 
$\int_a^b \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)\,dx = \lim\limits_{t \to a+}\int_t^b f(x)\,dx$

But if $f(x)$ is continuous at $[a,b]$
$g(t) =\int_t^bf(x)\,dx$ is continous because
$g(t) =\int_t^bf(x)\,dx=-\int_b^tf(x)\,dx$
$g'(t) = -f(t)$
$f(t)$ is continuous -> $g'(t)$ continuous -> $g(t)$ is continous

so $\lim\limits_{t \to a+}\int_t^b f(x)\,dx=\lim\limits_{t \to a+}g(t)=g(a)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$

Is this correct? how about when $f(x)$ is not continuous at $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: How do you define $h(x):=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)$ at $x=a$? To be a (proper) Riemann integral, you'd need to define it.

Comment: $h(a)$ is not defined. For example, $f(x)=x, g(x)=x-1, a=1, b=2$

Comment: Then it's can't be the Riemann integral of $h$ on $[a, b]$, because $h$ is not defined on $[a, b]$.

Comment: Then how about this integration? $\int_{-2}^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x}\,dx$ I think we can't integrate this because $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x}$ is not defined at [-2, -1]